# How to render multiple root elements in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I want to render two pages in Xamarin. One is the main page and the other one is a footer page- they both are .xaml files. The only problem is that the footer uses a ThriveGmbH.BottomNavigationBar.XF imported NuGet class and the Main Page uses a content page class. When I try to use both classes inside a single script I get a "multiple root elements" error. Is it possible to render both pages or call the footer page inside of the main page? Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is "ThriveGmbH.BottomNavigationBar.XF"?  Can you link to the nuget package or github page?

Comment: have you looked at the samples for the project?  They clearly show how to use it

Comment: Hi guys, this is the URL for their Github: https://github.com/thrive-now/bottom-navigation-bar-xf
The only samples I've been able to find anywhere is how to create the bottom navigation bar but I haven't found any sample which shows how to integrate it into any other page.

Comment: https://github.com/thrive-now/BottomNavigationBarXF/blob/master/example-xaml/BottomBarXFExampleXaml/BarPage.xaml - BottomBarPage is it's own type of page that you can place content into

Comment: Is it possible to place this page's content into other pages? Is there any reference in Xamarin's documentation?

Comment: this is a 3rd party control, not Xamarin.  Look at the sample page I just pointed you to

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Thank you.